# Crash during Quartz operations on large images

Tags: iphone

I have an app that can import images. My app doesn't need large images, so if I see an image larger than 512 pixels on a side, I resize it.

I'm using some image resizing functions that I borrowed from:

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way

The resizing functions work really well most of the time, but I have some large photos in my library that are 5616x3744. When I try to resize this image, it sometimes causes a crash while executing CGContextDrawImage() (about half the time it crashes, although once I was able to process about 20 images before it crashed). It is not consistent about which images it crashes on yet.

I haven't tried this in the simulator yet, but have been running on my iPad in develop mode while connected to the debugger. When the app crashes, it exits right out of the debugger and returns with signal "0".

I was wondering if there might be a memory issue, but when I run it with the allocations instrument, it doesn't go past about 44meg before crashing, and my app gets no memory warnings.

Is the resize operation just allocating a HUGE amount of memory that causes an out of memory crash without getting any kind of warning first?

I guess I could restrict my app to smaller images, but I would like to know why the crash is happening to make sure that it isn't something random that could bite me later.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Note ... I've done some more debugging and I can load 10 mega-pixel images with no problems at all (I tried over 100 consecutively). When the megapixel count gets up to around 20 megapixels, then the routine crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit more debugging and I think what is happening is that the OS is killing my App for allocating too much memory. Since it is done in a single operation, the OS doesn't get a chance to notify my app about running out of memory, and just kills the app. Kind of sad that an iPad can't even resize a single 20 megapixel photo without being killed. Hopefully the iPad 3 will have at least 1gig of memory! My iPhone4 will do 70 megapixel photos without a problem.